# Why does this condition of Delta complex prevents trivial complexes?

Tags: algebraic-topology

From Hatcher's textbook:

[image]

The author then states that "Among other things, this last condition rules out trivialities like regarding all the points of X as individual vertices."

I am failing to see why this is the case though. We can still express a circle as the union of singletons and have each 0 complex map to each singleton, then the preimage of each open set of the circle will be either the singleton (which is the entire space for the 0 complex) or the empty for all $\sigma_\alpha$ which are open.

Comment: Intuitively, if every point of a complex was an individual vertex then the topology would be discrete. Property (iii) rules that out "among other things" (assuming that there exists some $\alpha$ such that $n \ge 1$).

Answer (score 1):

Conditions (i) and (ii) only give a very weak relation between the topology of $X$ and the maps $\sigma_\alpha : \Delta^n \to X$. Essentially they say that $X$ is the disjoint union of the subsets $\sigma_\alpha(\mathring{\Delta^n})$ (condition (i)) and that the maps $\sigma_\alpha$ are compatible in a fairly evident sense (condition (ii)). The only sparse topological information is that the $\sigma_\alpha$ are continuous.

For example, if $X$ has the trivial topology, then **all** maps into $X$ are continuous so that the above decomposition of $X$ into the $\sigma_\alpha(\mathring{\Delta^n})$ is just a partition on the level of sets. In that case a $\Delta$-complex on $X$ can be defined as follows: For each $x \in X$ take $\sigma_x : \Delta^0 \to X$ to be the map with $\sigma(\Delta^0) = \{ x\}$. There are no other maps living on $\Delta^n$ for $n > 0$. This is an example of what Hatcher calls "triviality".