# Cell decompositions and cell complexes

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cw-complexes

Let me first state my definition of cell complexes.

**Definition 1:** Cellular decomposition of a topological space $X$ is a cover $\mathcal{E}$ of space $X$, equipped with a function deg: $\mathcal{E} \to \mathbb{Z}$, such that:

1. For any different sets $e, e' \in \mathcal{E}$, we have $e \cap e' = \emptyset$
2. $\mathcal{E}^{(-1)} = \emptyset$
3. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and any set $e \in \mathcal{E}_n$, there exist a continuous map $\phi: B^n \to X$, which maps the open unit ball int$B^n$ homeomorphically on set $e$ and for which $\phi(\partial B^n) \subset \cup \mathcal{E}^{(n-1)}$

Here, we use otations $\mathcal{E}_k = \text{deg}^{-1}(k) $ and $\mathcal{E}^{(k)} = \text{deg}^{-1}(\{ j \in \mathbb{Z} \; | \; j \leq k \})$.

**Definition 2:** Cell complex is the pair $(X, \mathcal{E})$, where $X$ is a topological space and $\mathcal{E}$ is its cellular decomposition.

**Definition 3:** CW complex is a Hausdorff cell complex $(X, \mathcal{E})$, such that

1. For each cell $e \in \mathcal{E}$, there exist cells $e_1, \ldots, e_m \in \mathcal{E}$, such that $\overline{e} \subset e_1 \cup \ldots \cup e_m$
2. Any subset $A \subset X$ is closed in $X$ iff for every cell $e \in \mathcal{E}$ the set $A \cap \overline{e}$ is closed in $\overline{e}$.

Now, my text provides no motivation or examples. So I was trying to think of some on my own. I would appreciate if someone explains what cellular composition of these examples looks like:

**Example 1:** Interval $[0,1]$. In this example, I suppose we would have $\mathcal{E} = \{ \{0\}, \{1\}, (0,1)\}$ with $\text{deg}(\{0\}) = \text{deg}(\{1\}) = 0$ and $\text{deg}((0,1)) = 1$. Conditions (1) and (2) are now clearly satisfied. Condition (3) is also satisfied; for $e = (0,1)$, the map $\phi: B^1 \to [0,1]$ can be translation plus contraction, and we have $\phi |_{\text{int} B^1}: \text{int}B^1 \to (0,1)$ homeomorphism, while also $\phi(\partial B^1) \subset \cup \mathcal{E}^{(0)}$. For $e = {0}$ and $e = {1}$ condition (3) also holds trivially. Is this reasoning okay?

**Example 2:** Interval $(0,1)$ (and similarly $[0,1)$). I don't know how one could find a cellular decomposition for this space, because of condition (3); I think the boundary of $B^1$ would not map in $\cup \mathcal{E}^{(0)}$. So, what to do here? In general, how to take care of open spaces?

**Example 3:** A cube with a dome on top, or any slightly more complicated object. How to find a cellular decomposition of such a space?

Comment: What is the source of this definiton?

Comment: Cellular decompositions in the sense of your question may be pathological. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4426628.

Comment: @PaulFrost the source is Mrčun: Topologija .

Comment: The first definition looks like an incomplete definition of a [CW-complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex). If you look, for example, in Hatcher's textbook, you will find that the complete definition specifies that the topology on $X$ is the weakest one for which each of the maps $\phi$ is continuous. You will also find many examples of CW complexes

Comment: @LeeMosher this is not the definition of CW complexes. My book distinguishes between cell complexes and CW complexes. I added the definition of CW complex for clarity.

Comment: That definition is equivalent to the one in Hatcher: item 2 is equivalent to the specification of the topology from Hatcher; and item 1 is redundant (i.e. it is a consequence of the other items, including the specification of the topology).